# Does Rust have a dlopen equivalent

Tags: plugins, rust

Does Rust have a way to make a program pluggable. In C the plugins I create are .so files that I load with dlopen. Does Rust provide a native way of doing the same thing?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [Rust FAQ](https://prev.rust-lang.org/en-US/faq.html#how-do-i-do-dynamic-rust-library-loading) officially endorses [libloading](https://crates.io/crates/libloading). Beyond that, there are three different options I know of:

- Use the [shared_library crate](https://crates.io/crates/shared_library)
- Use the [dylib crate](https://crates.io/crates/dylib).
- Use  [`std::dynamic_lib`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/dynamic_lib/), which is [deprecated](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27810) since Rust 1.5. (These docs are no longer available in version 1.32; it's likely the feature has been dropped altogether by now.)

I haven't tried any of these, so I cannot really say which is *best* or what the pros/cons are for the different variants. I'd strongly advise **against** using `std::dynamic_lib` at least, given that it's deprecated and will likely be made private at some point in the future.

Comment: Yeah, libloading appears to be the sanctioned way of doing this now.

Answer (score 13):

Exactly,

And below is the complete use case example:

```
use std::unstable::dynamic_lib::DynamicLibrary;
use std::os;

fn load_cuda_library()
{

    let path = Path::new("/usr/lib/libcuda.so");

    // Make sure the path contains a / or the linker will search for it.
    let path = os::make_absolute(&path);

    let lib = match DynamicLibrary::open(Some(&path)) {
        Ok(lib) => lib,
        Err(error) => fail!("Could not load the library: {}", error)
    };

    // load cuinit symbol

    let cuInit: extern fn(u32) -> u32 = unsafe {
        match lib.symbol("cuInit") {
            Err(error) => fail!("Could not load function cuInit: {}", error),
            Ok(cuInit) => cuInit
        }
    };

    let argument = 0;
    let expected_result = 0;
    let result = cuInit(argument);

    if result != expected_result {
        fail!("cuInit({:?}) != {:?} but equaled {:?}",
                argument, expected_result, result)
    }
}

fn main()
{
    load_cuda_library();
}
```

Comment: I assume this loads any library that is C compatible? And I would assume that loading the symbol like with dlopen doesn't actually know the function signature which means that you can't be really sure you are calling the function with the correct arguments. This would seem to break the safety that Rust gives you but I guess loading other code at will is not necessarily the safest thing to do in the first place.

Comment: You are quite right. Any library that is C compatible can be loaded. Unfortunately it breaks the safety. However the scheme above is subject to change. The Rust developers are going to add a safe way for  dynamic loading of libraries, see https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/458

Comment: For the recors, issue #458 has been closed, the new one is https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/15040

Comment: Has been moved again (since it didn't make it to the 1.0 version of Rust): https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/661

Comment: I don't think this should be the approved answer @Matt, it suggests the usage of unstable, not-easily-accessible functionality in Rust. The Rust FAQ gives a different suggestion than this (see my answer to this question for more detials).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. There's a module `std::unstable::dynamic_lib` that enables dynamic loading of libraries. It's undocumented, though, as it's a highly experimental API (everything in `std::unstable` is undocumented). As @dbaupp suggests, [the source](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/blob/master/src/libstd/unstable/dynamic_lib.rs) is the best documentation (current version is [af9368452](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/blob/af9368452d8578af219713b34f7e3be4bd085186/src/libstd/unstable/dynamic_lib.rs)).

Comment: ([The source](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/blob/af9368452d8578af219713b34f7e3be4bd085186/src/libstd/unstable/dynamic_lib.rs) is the best documentation.)