# How does one define optional methods on traits?

Tags: interface, rust, custom-type

Does Rust have a feature whereby I can create define potentially non-existent methods on traits?

I realize that `Option` can be used to handle potentially non-existent properties but I don't know how the same can be achieved with methods.

In TypeScript, the question mark denotes that the methods may potentially be non-existent. Here is an excerpt from RxJs:

```js
export interface NextObserver<T> {
  next?: (value: T) => void;
  // ...
}
```

If this feature does not exist in Rust, how should one think about dealing with objects whereby the programmer doesn't know whether a method will be present or not? Panic?

Comment: In the way you describe it, no Rust don't have optional method. You should give a usecase where we can give you possible solution instead of trying to mimic something from an another language.

Comment: "how should one think about dealing with objects whereby the programmer doesn't know whether a method will be present or not?", programmer is suppose to know if a method exist, maybe you want use [dynamic load of function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22461457/7076153) ?

Comment: @Stargateur Thank you for your answer. Usecase: implementing the observer pattern in Rust in a similar way to rxjs likeso: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/types.ts#L56

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can try using empty default implementations of methods for this:

```
trait T {
    fn required_method(&self);

    // This default implementation does nothing        
    fn optional_method(&self) {}
}

struct A;

impl T for A {
    fn required_method(&self) {
        println!("A::required_method");
    }
}

struct B;

impl T for B {
    fn required_method(&self) {
        println!("B::required_method");
    }

    // overriding T::optional_method with something useful for B
    fn optional_method(&self) {
        println!("B::optional_method");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A;
    a.required_method();
    a.optional_method(); // does nothing

    let b = B;
    b.required_method();
    b.optional_method();
}
```

[Playground](http://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dbc76710162daf3c53ff2544c55b9219&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)